# DrawerLayout add two home icons to my actionbar

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Following the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) I added a drawer to my activities but for some reason I get two home icons (see screen below).

I am not adding anything else to the actionbar, no custom view and I am not using SherlockActionBar. The only difference with the example is that I have a base activity class that enables the drawer and that all my activities sub-class from it.

[image]

Comment: What do you use for drawer icon? Maybe you are supplying R.drawable.ic_launcher to ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the [`ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle%28android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) object, the 3rd parameter, `drawerImageRes`, should be the icon for opening and closing the slide out pane (typically 3 stacked horizontal lines). It looks like you supplied that parameter as your launcher icon.

If you need the slide out artwork, you can download the official one [here](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20130926.zip), or use the [Android Asset Studio generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html).